# Telegram inline bot - can it be restricted to one supergroup?

Tags: inline, bots, telegram

Can a Telegram inline bot be restricted to one supergroup? In other words, we only want this bot to be used in one supergroup - nowhere else. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, the inline mode works in every chat.
You can allow to use the inline bot to a ristrect number of people simply checking user's id.

```
$inline_user_id = $update[inline_query][from][id]
```

Comment: Excellent info - very helpful. Thanks!